# email configuration in redmine throwing parsing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

We are new to ruby, we are trying to configure Redmine on our server, but facing the error, during configuring Redmine for Receiving Emails for receiving emails from IMAP/pop3 email servers. We are following (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails)

Error is

```
[root@redmine]# rake -f /app/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=hostname.com username=bug@hostname.com password=1234567890
(in /app/redmine)

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: compile error - syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
                             ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /app/redmine/Gemfile:31
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
 >  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
 #  gem "rbpdf", "~> 1.19.3"
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Version details

```
[root@redmine]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
[root@redmine]# bundle -v
Bundler version 1.16.1
[root@redmine]# gem -v
1.3.7.1
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? Is it 1.8.x?

Comment: [root@redmine]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Redmine won't work on such old version, upgrade it to 2.2 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use Ruby 1.9's hash syntax in a 1.8 version of Ruby. Your line should look like this instead:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
```

(or upgrade Ruby)